# In Novice Terms, How Does an Ordered Pair Relate to a Database Row (Tuple)?

Tags: relations, education

Im putting a technical presentation for an interview (topic I chose).  I am researching real-time data streaming.  I am familiar with what an ordered pair is as it pertains to a graph i.e (x, y) defines a point on the x,y axis.

May you explain to me how this relates to columns in a database?  Does this have to do with the index?

I'm trying to visualize this but all I can think about is result sets in the DBMS and want to learn how this applies.

Thanks

Comment: Why the downvote?  If the post is worthy of a down vote, then explain why.  I'm trying to learn.

Comment: in a database the columns are just like coordinate axes and the values (in each column) are points on these axes, so since the columns of a database are ordered (it matters which column is where) it is analogous to ordered pairs or ordered n-tuples in general

Comment: maybe this would be more relevant in stackoverflow or programers.se?

Comment: @NikosM. I understand your view on that...I wanted a more mathematical approach.  Thanks for your input.  I will also post on Stackoverflow...Im strongly predicting a downvote on there because there is no code involved.

Comment: check [Relational Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) which is the formal mathematical algebra of relational databases. Thereof all database operations are defined and used in algebraic terms (of which cartesian n-tuples is one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you're looking for is the *relation*. Relational databases are an application of the mathematical theory of relations.

If you have two sets, $A$ and $B$, you can form the set of all ordered pairs $(a, b)$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. We call this set of ordered pairs the *Cartesian product* of $A$ and $B$, denoted $A \times B$. In other words

$$A \times B = \{(a,b) : a \in A, b \in B   \}$$

For example if $A = B = \mathbb{R}$, then $A \times B = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^2$.

This is a set-theoretical way to think of the Cartesian plane as the product of the $x$- and $y$-axes.

Another example would be if $A = \{$apple, banana} and $B = \{$yellow, red} then

$A \times B =$ {(apple, yellow), (apple, red), (banana, yellow), (banana, red)}.

Now, what is a *relation* on $A$ and $B$? It's a *subset of their Cartesian product*.

For example if we wish to specify the relation "equals" on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ we would specify the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of exactly those pairs $(x,y)$ for which $x = y$.

So you see that we can express a relation as a subset of a Cartesian product.

In our fruit/color database, the relation of interest is the set of ordered pairs representing each fruit and its actual color. This is represented by the subset {(apple, red), (banana, yellow)}.

The key point is that *A relation between $A$ and $B$ is a subset of $A \times B$*.

In the general case, suppose you have $n$ sets $S_1, S_2, \dots, S_n$. Then a relation on these $n$ sets is just a subset of the Cartesian product of all of them, where instead of ordered pairs, the Cartesian product is the set of all *ordered n-tuples* formed from the sets.

You can now see that if you have a database table representing the employees at a company, the data in the database is a subset of the Cartesian product of sets representing the employee name, employee number, job title, salary, years on the job, etc.

Once we choose a subset of that Cartesian product, we have a database table populated with the employees and their respective information.

The rest of relational database theory is worked out in terms of [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) on sets.

To sum this up: A relation is a subset of the Cartesian product of a collection of $n$ sets; each set representing a column in a database table. The contents of the database are a particular set of $n$-tuples, each $n$-tuple representing a row of the database table.

Comment: Thank you...while I don't fully understand...this is the starting point I was looking for

Comment: @user216392 Im starting to understand now.  Your answer led me to this:  http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-e772ea8b8b552118dba12334d2149f77?convert_to_webp=true   I only have focused on applying business logic,  I am a double major in B.S. CIS and B.S. Supply Chain Management  I haven't ever studied Computer Science...so I haven't every paid dues to indexes...I am learning great stuff....Thanks again [so much]!!!  Is the difference between A x B and B x A the difference between LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN?

Comment: No, joins are something else entirely. When you swap all the ordered pairs in a set, what happens? If it's a graph in the plane, each pair (x,y) gets changed to the pair (y,x). It's like swapping the x and y axes. Or reflecting the graph of the set of points in the line y = x. Try it with some examples. Let y = x^2 and graph those points. Then let x = y^2 and graph those points. If anything, reversing (x,y) gives you an *index*. Instead of looking up x to find y, you look up y to find x. Instead of looking up apple to get red, you look up red to get apple.